# Lookup value in another sheet based on name

Tags: excel

I have a file that has:

sheet 1:

```
Name  Hours Price
-----------------
Name1 12    126.00 
Name2 14    161.00
Name3 8     100.00
Name4 10    135.00
```

sheet 2:

```
Name  Rate
---------
Name1 10.5
Name2 11.5
Name3 12.5
Name4 13.5
```

I want to multiply Hours by the names corresponding rate. So like Name1 = 12 * 10.5 = 126 and so on. Not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `VLOOKUP`:

(assuming Name is in `A1` in both sheets):

The formula in the `Price` column (C3 through C6) should be

```
=B3*VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A$3:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

translated:

```
=  B3   *VLOOKUP(  A3  ,  Sheet2!$A$3:$B$6   ,      2     ,     FALSE   )
={Hours}*VLOOKUP({Name},{Name+Rate in Sheet2},{2nd column},{exact match})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, how can I make it so that I have a single cell that encompasses: Name1 * rate + Name2 * rate + NameX * RateX etc?

Comment: Add a SUM() to the bottom of the Price column?

Comment: I don't actually have a price column, that was for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I would add a Price column (even if it's hidden) and use `SUM()` rather than adding multiple values in one formula.  Or add the Rate as a column and do a `SUMPRODUCT()`

Answer (score 0):

I think an rlly easy way if you want to do it over "code" in a excelcell then like this:

=IF(A1=Table2!A1;B1*Table2!B1)

=IF(CELL = CELL; THEN DO; ELSE DO)

If the names can be changing in the order, D Stanleys is better.

Otherwise VBA-Code would be also easy.

Comment: Excel does not have a `WHEN` function that I'm aware of.  Do you mean `IF`?

Comment: Oh sorry can be, didnt googled for the english name of the function, my excel wont change his language, and i just translatet it from german into english ;)